Finding good shift operators for XorShift
I'm not certain this is the right place to ask but I'll ask anyway. I've been messing around with XorShift random number generators, I've only implemented a simple one copied almost verbatim from the wiki page. The only think I changed originally is change the shifts to << 23; >> 17; << 26; and used a u128 state. I had to duplicate the random generator to still be random on multiple threads and I had to tinker a little to find good shift operations.
I got interested in how to get good shift values, so I made a little brute force test. Specifically I was searching for the smallest set of shift operations that would go trough all values (and otherwise as many unique values) breaking when I found a duplicate. For a u8 state got through all states with >> 1; << 1; >> 2;, a u16 state got through all states with >> 1; << 1; << 14;. When I tried this for u32, I didn't have enough memory anymore breaking at >> 1; << 5;
I didn't check if it went through all values consistently or only on the first go (but I presume it won't). Mainly because if I were to be able to find a good cycle for u128 that wouldn't be an issue. Unfortunately however my brute forcing results weren't very enlightening so I still don't have a clue how to find a good cycle.
I've tried to think of a way to predict the length of a cycle, but nothing useful came out of that.
Finally my concrete question, for an XorShift is there a reasonably simple way, which isn't brute force, to find a set of shift operations to get a good long cycle?

"Mainly because if I were to be able to find a good cycle for u128 that wouldn't be an issue." - actually, that's possible, with two observations: 1) it is possible to "fast forward" the operation $n$ steps in $O(\log n)$ time, and 2) if performing the operation $2^{128}-1$ times gives the original (nonzero) value, and if performing the operation $(2^{128}-1)/p$ times (for all prime factors $p$ of $2^{128}-1$ does not, then any nonzero value will have a cycle of $2^{128}-1$ long.  When I get time, I'll give a fuller answer

I'd usually get myself a little familiar with the concepts you're mentioning, but I have genuinely no clue how that could possibly work nor would I have a good idea of what to look up to find those answers. If you don't have time for a full answer, which I fully understand, do you mind mentioning some terms that I can look up myself?

Ok, I now have some time, so I'll lay out the basics.
First step: how to "fast forward" your construction.
One observation is that your operation is entirely bitwise-linear; that is, there exists a $128\times 128$ matrix that, when multiplied by the input, generates the output.  And, that matrix is easy to compute.
Obviously, computing the output using this matrix multiplication is slower than using the obvious code; however "though this be madness, yet there is method in't".
The second observation is that if we multiply two such $128 \times 128$ matricies $A \times B$ together, when we multiply the product by a 128 bit input, this has the effect of performing the operation $B$ first, and then operation $A$.  That is, if $A$ was 'performing your operation $a$ times, and $B$ was 'performing your operation $b$ times', then the effect of the matrix $A \times B$ is 'performing your operation $a+b$ times'.
This allows us to perform the operation in faster-than-linear time.  In the simplest case, to advance your operation 4 times, we can multiply by the matrix $A \times A \times A \times A = (A \times A) \times (A \times A)$ - this requires just 3 matrix multications, rather than 4.  That might not sound like such an impressive speed-up; however consider if we want to compute the matrix that performs your operation 1024 times, all we need to do is take your original matrix, and square it 10 times (where squaring a matrix means multiplying it by itelf).  More generally, to compute it $k$ times (for an arbitrary positive integer $k$), we just compute an addition chain that corresponds to $k$; this allows us to compute the matrix in $O(\log k)$ matrix multiplications.  For example, to fast forward the operation $2^{128}-1$ steps, instead of calling your fast code $2^{128}-1$ times, we can use the binary method and perform 255 matrix multiplications (and the binary method is not the most efficient; however it's a good place to start, and is only a factor of less than 2 from being optimal).

Now, with that done, we look at how we can verify whether your operation (with specific shifts) actually achieves maximal cycle length.
Now, we know that, for your operation, the all zero vector will always map to the all zero vector, and so that's a cycle of one.  Hence, the largest possible cycle for everything else is a cycle of length $2^{128}-1$ (and we know that is achievable with a linear operation, because of the existence of LFSR with a primitive feedback polynomial).
So, the first thing we can check is "what does your operation cycled $2^{128}-1$ look like?  If the matrix corresponding to that is anything other than the identity matrix (that is, one that maps anything to itself), then we know that an input must have a cycle length less than $2^{128}-1$ (because it cannot have a larger one).
If that is the identity matrix, then the cycle length must be $(2^{128}-1)/k$ for some integer $k$; the next thing to check is if $k=1$.
For that, we can just check the operation iterated $(2^{128}-1)/p$ times (for all primes $p$ that are divisors of $2^{128}-1$); if $k$ has $p$ as a factor, then that will be the identity matrix.  Hence, if it is not the identity matrix for all prime factors $p$, then $k$ must not be divisible by any factor, and so the only possibility is $k=1$, and we are done...
The only question I didn't try to address is "what are the prime factors of $2^{128}-1$ anyways?"  Well, $2^{128}-1 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 257 \cdot 641 \cdot 65537 \cdot 274177 \cdot 6700417 \cdot 67280421310721$
Ok, actually implementing this is a bit of work - but it is feasible, and will allow you to perform the test you are looking for...

That all actually made sense! Thank you very much! I'll brush up on my linear algebra soon and see how far I get. Again thank you for your detailed answer!

Thank you for opening my horizons. Both the question and the answer are great. Do you have any other studies/experiments for number generators?
